# How do I get sencha js and JSP to work together?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, sencha-touch, extjs

I am looking into using Sencha touch to create the "view" portion of my webapp so that it will work on mobile devices. The web app is created using Spring MVC and therefore the "view" part of it is actually rendered using JSP.

Suppose I pass a model called "invoice" from my controller to my view, in JSP, I would get the model as such:

```
${invoice.number}
```

However, when I use Sencha touch, since all the coding is done in a js file, how do I call that model?

I tried something like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Landing',

    launch: function(){
        Ext.create("Ext.TabPanel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            items: [
                   {
                       title: 'Landing',
                       iconCls: 'landing',
                       html: [
                              '<h1>Invoice Id is ${invoice.number}</h1>'
                              ]
                    }


                    ]
            }
            ); // --Ext.create
        }

}); // --Ext.application
```

But that does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the way we go about this is decoupling the Sencha Touch application and the back-end as much as possible. You would have your Spring app expose an API (read: RESTful Services) that Sencha Touch would use. The data (models) would be serialized over JSON or XML (or whatever format you would like) and parsed by Sencha Touch's readers.

Sencha Touch is designed to be a MVC application framework in it of itself.

You can take a look at these articles:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-1

http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/structuring-your-sencha-touch-application